# Outlook add-in O365 login flow using javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, office365, outlook-addin

I'm implementing Outlook add-in to my site. I need to implement authenticate Office 365 login functionality.I tried this url to login to office 365 :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?api-version=2.0&client_id=XXX&response_type=code&amp;redirect_uri=https://mysiteurl/auth.php&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
```

When I hit this URL directly from the browser, I'm getting the response as

```
Array
(
    [code] => M26235f9c-3bb8-aa61-14ab-5d8110dc3f1a
)
```

But the issue is when I try to hit this URL from outlook add-in, it returns an error

> "Refused to display
>   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?api-version=2.0&client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://mysiteurl/auth.php&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. ".

Why this error occurred and how to fix this.

When I hit this URL from browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?api-version=2.0&client_id=XXX&response_type=code&amp;redirect_uri=https://mysiteurl/auth.php&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
```

I'm getting the result:

```
Array
(
    [code] => M26235f9c-3bb8-aa61-14ab-5d8110dc3f1a
)
```

Is that what I'm trying is correct or are there some other ideas to login with O365 in outlook add-in?
Can anyone suggest any reference tutorial to implement login with O365 in outlook add-in?

Comment: I have also refereed this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph. but i didn't understood this flow. I want implementation code with example.

Comment: Are you testing this on Outlook Web application (OWA) or Outlook Desktop application?

Comment: Outlook Web application from https://outlook.live.com/mail/inbox

Answer (score 0):

As the [error suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), you cannot display this page in an Frame/IFrame/Embed

> "Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?api-version=2.0&client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://mysiteurl/auth.php&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. ".

You will have to use dialog to handle you authentication flow.

[How to use the Dialog API in your Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)